Do local unitaries commute with the partial trace?
I want to use this condition as part of a larger proof and I believe it is true (due to the no signalling theorem in physics) but I cannot seem to prove it.
Let $\rho \in \mathcal{H}_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B$ be a bipartie operator acting on a finite dimensional Hilbert space.
Let $U_{A}$ be a unitary operator acting on $\mathcal{H}_A$ only.
Is the following condition true:
$U_A \textrm{tr}_B\big[\rho] U_A^\dagger = \textrm{tr}_B\big[(U_A \otimes \mathbb{I}_B)\rho(U_A \otimes \mathbb{I}_B)^\dagger \big]$
An answer was given here, but I do not understand their proof. Any help would be much appreciated

What exactly don’t you understand about the linked proof? It’s just algebraic manipulation, nothing deep going on.

I don't understand "Einstein's summation convention". I was hoping there would be a way to prove it using the partial trace formula (which I do understand) without having to rely on Einstein's summation convention.

Emm, it’s just a convention to sum over any index appearing at least twice, not any theorem or anything like that. So if you just put a summation sign in front any time you see an index appearing twice in a formula, you get a proof using the definition of partial trace, as you want.

(And, if you’re learning physics, you should really learn to use Einstein’s summation convention. It’s quite standard in physics literature.)

To provide an alternative proof: A nice way of showing this result is to use the trace duality of the partial trace, that is, the partial trace is the unique linear map which satisfies
$$
{\rm tr}\big( X{\rm tr}_B(Y) \big)={\rm tr}\big( (X\otimes{\bf1}_B)Y \big)
$$
for all $X$ acting on $A$ and all $Y$ acting on the composite system $AB$. With this in mind we compute
\begin{align*}
{\rm tr}\big( X\,\color{red}{{\rm tr}_B\big((U_A \otimes {\bf1}_B)\rho(U_A \otimes {\bf1}_B)^\dagger \big)}\big)
&={\rm tr}\big((X\otimes{\bf1}_B)(U_A \otimes {\bf1}_B)\rho(U_A \otimes {\bf1}_B)^\dagger\big)\\
&={\rm tr}((U_A \otimes {\bf1}_B)^\dagger(X\otimes{\bf1}_B)(U_A \otimes {\bf1}_B)\rho\big)\\
&={\rm tr}\big((U_A^\dagger XU_A\otimes{\bf1}_B)\rho\big)\\
&={\rm tr}\big(U_A^\dagger XU_A{\rm tr}_B(\rho)\big)\\
&={\rm tr}\big(X\color{red}{U_A{\rm tr}_B(\rho)U_A^\dagger }\big)\,.
\end{align*}
Because $X$ was arbitrary, the red expressions have to coincide, i.e. because ${\rm tr}(XZ)={\rm tr}(XZ')$ for all $X$ implies $Z=Z'$ we get
$$
U_A{\rm tr}_B(\rho)U_A^\dagger ={\rm tr}_B\big((U_A \otimes {\bf1}_B)\rho(U_A \otimes {\bf1}_B)^\dagger \big)
$$
as desired.

Amazing, thank you!
